# How to find alpha and beta from a Gamma distribution?

Tags: r, gamma-distribution

The task: Using the method of moments model the data (sample) as a set of 20 independent observations from a Gamma(λ, k) distribution.

I have found the mean and variance but unsure how to find alpha and beta?

```
data = 100.2,90.6,47.7,24.7,77.5,88.8,168.7,87.2,102.5, 22.8,49.0,75.2, 123.7,182.3, 101.6,48.1,64.3,71.2,135.5,217.5
mu = (1/20)*sum(data)
u=0
for (i in 1:20){
  u[i]=(data[i]-mu)^2
}
v = (1/20)*sum(u)
v
```

Comment: What are "alpha" and "beta"? There are two common parameterizations of the gamma distribution, and your post doesn't make clear which you're referring to, especially because you write about the $\text{Gamma}(\lambda,k)$ distribution. Or are "alpha" and "beta" referring to something else, such as the mean or the variance?

Answer (score 10):

For a $\mathrm{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta)$ distributed variable $X$, expectation value (mean) $\mathrm{E}[X]$ and variance $\mathrm{Var}(X) = \mathrm{E}[(X - \mathrm{E}[X])^2]$ are related to parameters $\alpha, \beta$ as follows:

$$\mathrm{E}[X] = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}\,,$$
$$\mathrm{Var}(x) = \frac{\alpha}{\beta^2}\,.$$

Therefore

$$\alpha = \frac{\mathrm{E^2}[X]}{\mathrm{Var}(x)}\,,$$

$$\beta = \frac{\mathrm{E}[X]}{\mathrm{Var}(x)}\,.$$

Comment: The values of mean and variance given in the answer above are not those given in the following website. They are correct only if beta is interpreted as the rate parameter, but conventionally it denotes the inverse, ie the scale parameter. https://wiki.analytica.com/index.php?title=Gamma_distribution